# Valum File Uploader with Cropper will not work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, valums-file-uploader

I found this demo but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. I got everything working in  my application and realized it doesnt work on IE!!! The cropping console would not come up in Internet Explorer. Anyone know why?

Andrew Valums' Ajax Upload which can be found at http://valums.com/ajax-upload/.
Use IMGSelectArea 
Demo is here

http://html5.sapnagroup.com/demos/dragDropUploadsCrop/